# How can we increase speed of 3g internet?

Tags: internet, 3g

I use 3G internet.
My modem works excellent in some places of my city,
but in some it works terrible. Speed is low.

How can I increase the speed of it?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot "increase" the speed of the 3G connection that you have to more than what the service provider has installed or provided for. However, you can do the following to make use of as much of connectivity is available.

- Whatever you are using (USB dongle, direct modem, etc.) - attach an antenna to it. By far, this is your best bet.
- Try to get away from signal-interfering stuff. Electric lines, tram lines, microwaves, radio broadcast towers and other sources of electromagnetic radiation will always interfere with your 3G signal and reduce the effective bandwidth you can use.
- "*Encourage*" others to use wifi or other means to connect, assuming you want to stick to 3G in spite of other means. This means suggesting to the local coffee shop owner to install a wifi hotspot, or preaching to your friends how they are better off not connecting at all and just watching the Youtube video on your screen. The basic problem is over-subscription, and your objective is to reduce competition.

Comment: I am using 3g modem. How can I attach an antenna to it? <br /> I heard that we may enhance speed by making shape of antenna from plastic, etc. Did you hear about it?

Comment: You are not going to increase the speeds of a 3G with a plastic antenna.  You would at the very least need a metal antenna.

Comment: @AtaA-Design - One thing which sometimes helps if you are using a USB 3g dongle, is to attach it via a USB cable rather than plugging it directly into your PC. If your PC is producing any interference at the radio frequencies used by your 3g modem then moving it further away will reduce that interference. I find hanging my 3g dongle above my head can help get a better signal.

Comment: @MarkBooth, thanks. I will try using it in that way. I have usb cable.

Comment: loll... plastic antenna.

Answer (score 2):

3G is needs a good signal and in patchy areas your packets will get lost, and will need to resend and acknowledge.. that is the main problem of it slowing down and then speeding up again.

You can solve your problem by using a [GSM/CDMA/3G/HSDPA](http://www.myamplifiers.com/index-uk.html?gclid=CKSXjrjd6q0CFecmtAodMD2q5w) Amplifier

[3G Amplifier](http://www.myamplifiers.com/wireless_phone_booster_at4000w.html)

[image]

There are other ones out there, but these a pretty cheap.. they used to cost about 500EURO/800EURO.. but are becoming more popular.

Answer (score 1):

Increase your internet speed by other tricks:

1. Go to your Desktop
2. Right click on "My computer"
3. Select "Properties"
4. Click on "Hardware" tab
5. Click "Device manager"
6. You see the Device manager window
7. Click "Ports(COM & LPT)"
8. Double click on "Communication Ports"
9. Go to "Communication Port properties"
10. Go the "Port Setting"
11. Change your "Bits per second" to "128000".
12. and "Flow control" change to "Hardware".

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [Opera Turbo](http://www.opera.com/browser/turbo/). Don't use it for anything you wouldn't do on a public machine.